# (Chess game)Function that returns possible moves of pawn

Tags: c++, matrix, chess

I'm writing a C++ chess game.I have an abstract class Piece and classes which inherit it.Class Piece has pure virtual method which returns all possible moves.But I have a problem with pawn position, because for each player pawn can move only forward, but in the board(which is matrix of Piece) forward appears different for each player.How can I implement **possibleMoves()** for pawns ?
Thanks!

```
class Piece
{
    public:
        Piece(std::string, char verticalPosition, char horizontalPosition);

    virtual std::pair<char,char>* possibleMoves() const = 0;
    virtual ~Piece();
protected:
    std::string name;
    std::pair <char,char> initPosition;
    std::pair <char,char> currPosition;
};
```

Comment: I would think a pawn would know: 1) what colour it is, and 2) what its current position is. Then white pawns move from low numbers to high (they start in row 2) and black pawns move from high numbers to low (they start in row 7) (I assume 1-indexing as in standard chess [algebraic notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_%28chess%29)).

Comment: why are you returning a pointer to a pair of `char`s?

Comment: Return `std::vector<std::pair<char, char>>`, not `std::pair<char, char>*`.

Comment: woof woof food please, my paws are tired.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the direction the pawn can move into its constructor as a parameter and store as a member variable.  Use this when determining possible moves for the pawn.

Answer (score 0):

As BobTFish said in comments, the pawn object should know it's
color.  As for the position, I think I'd pass it as an argument
to `possibleMoves`; you probably also have to pass the board, so
that `possibleMoves` can detect moves which are captures (and en
passant, which gets more complicated, since it is only valid the
first time the possibility arises).